# Persistence sensor

Tags: sensor

I need to detect an item placed in a metal box. Minimum item width is 1 cm. Material - any. What sensor should I use to detect it? Can I use something like car alarm systems which detect whatever is placed inside? Is it possible to buy such sensors? What keyword/keywords should I use to find them?

[image]

Comment: It may be simpler to detect that the door has opened and closed rather than directly detecting something inside the box.  Would that be acceptable?

Comment: No, need to detect if might something was left.

Comment: Is it for detecting whether a letter is in a mailbox? Use 3-4 light barriers from top of the mailbox to the bottom.

Comment: Can you put a kitchen scale in the bottom of the box?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxDBa3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This requires precision beam reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It depends also on the size of the box, if the sensor (ie. proximity sensor) can detect 1cm width pieces, but they can be placed in a box say 20x20x20cm, chances are that it won't sense it.

The "car alarm" aproach wouldn't work because they sense movement or vibration, not presence.

There are "volumetric" sensors for this kind of purposes (usually the measured volume belongs to a fluid), but are very expensive (and for this purpose would be like killing an ant with a machine gun)

The simplest aproach i can think of, is multiple proximity sensors, located in specific points inside the box, to cover most of the posibilities, and connect the outputs in series (if they are NC) or in parallel (if they are NO).

Regarding the sensor in itself you can look for proximity sensor that works with light, ultrasound, maybe capacitive sensors. (ie. inductive sensors wouldn't work for they only sense metallic objects).

Hope this helps.